# Htaccess and PHP redirect, page not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a litle problem with a redirect, using PHP I make a 301 redirect to this URL (vars are from a search form):

```
ddddd.com/ads-CATEGORY-CITY/?var1=1&var2=2 (many vars here, not a fixed number, also the URL can have 0 "extra vars" so it will end at the second "/")
```

From this ugly URL:

```
ddddd.com/ads.php?type=CATEGORY&c=CITY&var1=1&var2=2
```

In my header file I have this code for the redirect:

```
function redirect() {
    if($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]=="") return false;  
    if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/ads.php')!==false) return false;

    $rewrittenURL = "ads-";
    $appendVars = "?";

    if(isset($_GET["type"])&&$_GET["type"]!="") $rewrittenURL .= $_GET["type"]."-";
    if(isset($_GET["c"])&&$_GET["c"]!="")  $rewrittenURL .= $_GET["c"]."/"; 

    if(isset($_GET["var1"])&&$_GET["var1"]!="") $appendVars .= "var1=".$_GET["var1"]."&";
    if(isset($_GET["var2"])&&$_GET["var2"]!="") $appendVars .= "var2=".$_GET["var2"]."&";
    [... more vars here ...]

    $appendVars = substr($appendVars, 0, -1);

    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: http://ddddd.com/'.$rewrittenURL.$appendVars);
}
if(PAGE=="ads.php") redirect();
```

And my htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=([^&]+)&c=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ads.php$ /ads-%1-%2/?%3 [L,R=301]
```

And I get an infinite loop :) I also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^ads-(.*)-(.*)/(.*)$ ads.php?tip=$1&j=$2&$3 [QSA,L]
```

Same loop... I need some help from someone with more experience :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in your htaccess by putting this code into it (you don't need PHP anymore)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/app/ads\.php\?type=([^&]+)&c=([^&]+)&?([^\s]+)?\sHTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule . /app/ads-%1-%2/?%3 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ads-([^\-]+)-([^\-]+)/$ /app/ads.php?type=$1&c=$2 [L,QSA]
```